# Is it possible to modify WSO2 token response?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2

we using WSO2 to generate token now I like to add custom parameters to that response payload

Current response :

```
{"access_token":"6a841cf7-fad1-3f1d-8e9a-d0f692beedd3","scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":2203}
```

I like to modify :

```
{"access_token":"6a841cf7-fad1-3f1d-8e9a-d0f692beedd3","scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":2203,"app_name":"ABC"}
```

how can i add new attribute "app_name":"ABC" in response ?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. The implementation class is configured like this in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`.

```
    <SupportedResponseTypes>
        <SupportedResponseType>
            <ResponseTypeName>token</ResponseTypeName>
            <ResponseTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler</ResponseTypeHandlerImplClass>
        </SupportedResponseType>
```

Here, you can have your own implementation. You can build a jar with your class (only) and put it inside `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/lib/`

The current implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/authz/handlers/TokenResponseTypeHandler.java).

Comment: do you know after new implementation where that jar file need to put and it should contain all dependency lib in that jar or only custom implementation class.

Comment: if you find any sample or step to follow example then share that link that would be good.

Comment: Updated the answer. 

You can create a simple maven project. Required dependencies can be found in the pom.xml of the original implementation.