# Can I customize WSO2 APIM token response JSON attributes?

Tags: oauth, wso2-api-manager, wso2

By default, WSO2 returns a JSON when you send a token request to /token that looks like this:

```
{
"access_token": "b73fc57e-83cc-3550-87ce-d015611da33a",
"scope": "scope1 scope2",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 1336
}
```

What i want is to fully customize the JSON output, being able to add and remove attributes, to get something like this instead:

```
{
"access_token": "b73fc57e-83cc-3550-87ce-d015611da33a",
"scope": "scope1 scope2",
"day": "monday",
"name": "mark"
}
```

I have implemented a custom grant that gets some data from another service and I want the JSON to include it as part of the response. I am very new to WSO2 and all I have found about this is this other question [Is it possible to modify WSO2 token response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579717/is-it-possible-to-modify-wso2-token-response?r=SearchResults&s=1|121.1932)

The proposed solution there is to implement a new TokenResponseTypeHandler, but as far as I've seen that class only sets the variables in a OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext object type, which are the ones that appear later in the JSON attributes (e.g. .setScope() sets the value for the "scope" attribute in the json), but no actual JSON formatting is done there and I can't find any information about who does it or where this OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext is being extracted after these handlers.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how can I do it and where? I am using WSO2 API Manager 3.0

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to send some hardcoded values? or from where do you plan to read the values to be set in the response?

Comment: I ended up using the JWT token issuer and adding my values as custom claims, which im getting from ldap calls. Anyway, could it be possible to delete some of the default values in the response JSON?  Not returning the "expires_in", maybe.